# Is it possible to create all folders in a path if they do not exist ? (Java/android)

Tags: java, android, file

i'm using quite long paths in an android application and I'd like to know if it is possible to magically create all non-existent folders in a given path ?
ex: RandomFolder/itDoesNotExist/itDoesNotExist2/myfile is it possible to create both folder in a single line in Java ?
I'm sure a while loop + file.exist & file.isDir would work but i'd like to know it is already implemented
Thanks for your help ! (yes this is my first post here)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's a custom to show what you have tried that didn't work so the community can help you past that

Comment: Call `mkdirs()` on a `File` that represents your desired target directory.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.